# Email attribute on data annotation are giving weired results for two scenarios

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting strange behaviour with the Email attribute (Data annotation extension ). When I import employees from CSV file it failing that email is not valid when that column is empty but it work perfect when I create employee from form even if I leave e mail empty. I don’t know why is this two behaviour for the same property.

Comment: Please give some code to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing wrong on your code this is a bug according to me in email attribute in data annotation package. They are checking isnull within the property but it should have to be IsNullOrEmpty check your import property whether it is empty if empty pass as null problem should solve. The reason this only happen on CSV because on excel sheet it just empty not null.

For your reference see the data annotation de-compile code.

```
namespace DataAnnotationsExtensions
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EmailAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

public EmailAttribute()
: base(DataType.EmailAddress)
{
}

public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
{
if (ErrorMessage == null && ErrorMessageResourceName == null)
{
ErrorMessage = ValidatorResources.EmailAddressAttribute_Invalid;
}

return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
}

public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
if (value == null)
{
return true;
}

string valueAsString = value as string;
return valueAsString != null && _regex.Match(valueAsString).Length > 0;
}
}
}
```

Have a great day